# How to get the value from textarea in Unity using c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to output any value inside a textarea. But I can't seem to find what am I doing wrong.

```
public string stringToEdit = "";

void OnGUI(){
    stringToEdit = GUI.TextArea (new Rect (20, 150, 550, 400), stringToEdit, 200);
}

public void run(){
    showThis (stringToEdit);
}

public void showThis(string a){
    Debug.Log (a);
}
```

I have a button called RUN and gave it the function run().

Whenever I press the button, the log is always empty even though the textarea has texts in it.

Comment: var text : TextEditor = GUIUtility.GetStateObject((TextEditor), GUIUtility.keyboardControl); // compare with text .

Comment: try above and let me know.